# How do i use a python variable in the middle of a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

How do I use a python variable in the middle of a javascript code?

I want to put the variable where it says `'test';`

```
test = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#react-root').innerText = 'test';")
```

Comment: Can't you just use string format? The javascript is just a string that happens to be JS code as far as Python is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use [string interpolation](http://zetcode.com/python/fstring/):

```
test = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

driver.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#react-root').innerText = '{test}';")
```

Comment: driver.execute_script(`document.querySelector('#react-root').innerText = '${test}';`)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: How is your JavaScript code being executed? Are you using Node.js? Browser code transpiled using Babel or TypeScript?

Comment: Oh, your script is in Python and the string is in JavaScript. Let me fix the answer.

Comment: I'm using python and selenium for browser automation with chrome driver.

Comment: Hi, Telmo, could you help me? I'm trying to do this same script but with a list but it doesn't work. ```driver.execute_script(f"document.querySelector('#react-root').innerText = '{test[listposition]}';") ```